# android activity orientation changing whole application orientation

Tags: orientation, landscape, portrait

I have set orientation of my activity 1 to portrait. Now when I start my activity 2 from activity 1, my second activity orientation becomes portrait, and it does not change to landscape. 
Any suggestions what must be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in your manifest file whenever you will rotate the screen will change

```
<activity
            android:name=".Login"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"

            >
        </activity>



android:screenOrientation=["unspecified" | "user" | "behind" |
                                     "landscape" | "portrait" |
                                     "reverseLandscape" | "reversePortrait" |
                                     "sensorLandscape" | "sensorPortrait" |
                                     "sensor" | "fullSensor" | "nosensor"]
```

Comment: i am not able to add android:screenOrientation=["unspecified" | "user" | "behind" |
                                     "landscape" | "portrait" |
                                     "reverseLandscape" | "reversePortrait" |
                                     "sensorLandscape" | "sensorPortrait" |
                                     "sensor" | "fullSensor" | "nosensor"] to my manifest file. it only takes one parameter for orientation

Comment: I edited the manifest manually. But, when I deploy again the manifest file overwriiten. I want to set Landscape mode only. How can I fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

set this attribute to your second activity in your manifest
android:screenOrientation="landscape"

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Comment: i dont want my second activity to be landscape only it should change according to the orientation of the phone

Comment: Always reset to 'unspecified' when deploy the application.